# How can I install couchdb 1.2.0 in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: couchdb, ubuntu-13.10

I need to install an older version of couchdb, Ubuntu 13.10 only has 1.4. I tried adding `ppa:nilya/couchdb-1.2` but it didn't work.